# Is it possible to detect ctrl key state on dblclick event

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google maps API version 3.  I would like my double click event handler to work as follows:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function(e) {
  if (/* ctrl is pressed */) {
    doSomething(e)
  } else {
    doSomethingElse(e)
  }
});
```

It looks the the event handler only provides a MouseEvent which does not contain information about the keyboard state.  I need the LatLng information so I doubt that I can use JQuery's event handling.

Am I out of luck here?

Comment: I suppose you could keep a global variable that says if ctrl is pressed down and update it using jQuery event handling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just cache the control key state

```
var ctrlPressed = false;
function cacheIt(event) {
    ctrlPressed = event.ctrlKey;
}
document.onkeydown = cacheIt;
document.onkeyup = cacheIt;
```

Now, `ctrlPressed` should always reflect whether or not the control key is down.

Comment: I was worried about cases where the the keyup/keydown event takes place outside the view port, like in the address bar, but the following seems to work regardless.  Heres my code, its basically what you showed. var ctrlKey = false; $(window).keydown(function(e){
            ctrlKey = e.ctrlKey;
        }).keyup(function(e){
            ctrlKey = e.ctrlKey;            
        });
    }

Comment: Both clarkf & Lawrence Barsanti's work on FF, IE & Chrome on Windows.  On Ubuntu Chrome the boolean is backwards?

Comment: On Windows, Chrome, if Ctrl is released when the mouse pointer is outside the Chrome window, the event is lost

Answer (score 3):

When caching key presses, I always bind a function to the blur event of the window object which clears any cached key presses. Otherwise you get stuck keys if the window loses focus.

Here's an example using jQuery:

```
$(window).blur( function () {
  // Clear cached key presses here
})
```