# How to detect Ctrl + Mouse dblckick using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to detect event like `Ctrl + DblClick` using jQuery. For `dblclick` I already have dblclick event. Is it possible to recognize the event without setting flag on keypress event?

Comment: Here there is a solution for you that might work:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990893/is-it-possible-to-detect-ctrl-key-state-on-dblclick-event

Answer (score 5):

look at the passed jQuery `event` object. There is a boolean property called `ctrlKey`.

```
$(window).on("dblclick", function(e) {
   console.log(e.ctrlKey); 
});
```

here's a simple example: http://jsbin.com/ugocaf/2/edit